# Error 1330. Visual studio 2008, cab11.cab has invalid digital signature

Tags: visual-studio-2008, failed-installation

When I am installing VS2008,via alchohol120 as it is ISO file, it gives me this error
"Error 1330.A fiel that is required cannot be installed because the cabinet file g:\cab11.cab has an invalid signature. THis may indicate that the cabinet fiel is corrupt."

I have tried few things like, choosing custom installation and unchecked option for SQL express and visual c++, but no help.

Then I checked digital signature of cab11.cab, it has a red cross on it, tried to install certificate , but again no help.

Even tried to copy the content of the folder to my HDD from virtual drive, but it says "File Integrity violated"

So can any one tell me what to do now.

Comment: Still having hard time installing it, please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Problem has been resolved.
What I did was,
When I checked that cab file's signature it said valid from 2007 to2009, so i just changed the date of the system to 2008 recopy the file to harddrive and remounted it , and it works, but still need to chekc if it works fine, will update once satisfied with its work.

Comment: Interesting ... I checked my ISO and it uses the same certificate for signing, but I didn't have any problems installing Visual Studio. Thank you for posting your solution :)